# NSInternalInconsistencyException occurs intermittently when using gocv on macOS

Tags: macos, opencv, go

I have this code using gocv(*provides Go language bindings for OpenCV*).
It simply draw some rectangles on the image and show the result.

```
func main() {
resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:6060/template-match")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(body))
var data Response
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
srcImage := gocv.IMRead("./images/src1.jpg", gocv.IMReadColor)
for i := 0; i < len(data.Data); i++ {
    gocv.Rectangle(&srcImage, data.Data[i], color.RGBA{R: 255}, 2)
}
window := gocv.NewWindow("match-result")
window.IMShow(srcImage)
gocv.WaitKey(0)
fmt.Println(data.Data, data.Msg)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
```

I'm really confused because this error does not occur every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used this library, but it looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/issues/599#issuecomment-579112179) – and, since you mentioned it happens only sometimes, it certainly sounds like the error is dependent upon thread context. The answer there (from the library author) points to https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread, so your main package should implement something like

```golang
func init() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
}
```